# How to Increase sleep time of Pixelsense device , when it is in surface mode

Tags: pixelsense

when i am playing with my Pixelsense apps in surface mode OR in Surface Cell (Test mode) , my pixelsense device is active until I play my apps , as I stop playing with apps after 5 min the device goes to sleep mode .

I wants to active my device always, even though user is not interacting with apps . Is it feature of Pixelsense device which make device in sleep mode OR it is part of my application.

Please help me.

Thanks & regards

Anupam Mishra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution , I would like to share the link

**http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697101.aspx**
From the above link you can change that on your device to whatever you need with a registry change.

Thanks